# How to set a whole Page to responsive Design with gwt-bootstrap?

Tags: gwt, gwt-bootstrap

I'm building a web application for Tablet. I code the css first myself. Now i added some widgets which use gwt-bootstrap. Well now i saw that gwt-bootstrap has some Methods like : `setHideOn(Device.PHONE)`

I'm  trying now to added such a method to my whole app to make it responsive. How should i process?

Comment: can you elaborate your question? it is little bit confuse!!!

Answer (score 2):

Adding this to your *.gwt.xml file:

```
<set-property name="bootstrap.responsiveDesign" value="true"/>
```

Will enable responsive design.

The `setHideOn(Device.PHONE)` that you said is for hide/show specific widgets in specific cases.